# Failed to use react-bootstrap in meteor with Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: meteor, browserify, react-bootstrap

I want to use react-bootstrap in meteor. I used meteorhacks:npm and cosmos:browserify by following the instructions at:
https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client-npm/

In myproj_root/packages.json, I added this line:

`{
  "react-bootstrap": "0.28.3",
  "externalify" : "0.1.0"
}`

After "meteor run", npm packages were automatically installed based on the command-line output. DropdownButton example works:

```
var {DropdownButton, MenuItem, Modal} = ReactBootstrap;

renderDropdownButton() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DropdownButton  title="Menu">
        <MenuItem eventKey="1">New Post</MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    </div>
  );
},
```

However, when I tried Modal,

```
NewPostModal = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal onRequestHide={() => {}}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>     
        </Modal>
     </div>
    );
  }
});
```

the following error is thrown:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `NewPostModal`

The problem seems to be that Modal.Header, Modal.Title are not recognized. Below are some of my package list info:

- Meteor: 1.2.1
- react                   0.14.3* Everything you need to use React with Meteor
- meteorhacks:npm           1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
- meteorhacks:ssr           2.2.0  Server Side Rendering for Meteor with
- meteorhacks:subs-manager  1.6.3  Subscriptions Manager for Meteor
- cosmos:browserify         0.9.4* Bundle NPM modules for client side with Brow...

Any help is appreciated.